# UISearchDisplayController layout issue in landscape with iOS7

Tags: uitableview, layout, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` which has a bad layout in iOS7, in landscape only. Here are the screenshots :

- Before searching
  [image]
- During search (notice the search bar doesn't go behind the status bar)
  [image]
- When search is done
  [image]

I end up with a gap of 10 pixels. My `UISearchDisplayController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` and the weird thing is that it works properly while in portrait orientation.

EDIT:

Here is a [link to a video showing the bug](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6543817/bug-MC.mov). Any help would be great !

EDIT 2:
Ok I made some progress on that. The thing is that my table view with the search display controller is presented from a view controller which has a modal presentation style set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` ! If I load it with the default modal presentation style, all work as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I had the same problem, I had

- UINavigationController presented as UIModalPresentationFormSheet
- UITableViewController with UISearchDisplayController UISearchBar as tableHeaderView
- When activated, the UISearchBar showed 20 pixels below the top of the modal view.

Unfortunately, the temporary fix appears to be to set edgesForExtendedLayout to UIRectEdgeNone.